# Unity Script that creates obstacles is not running in build but runs as expected in the editor

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, build

There is this naughty script that runs and works bug-free in the editor but does nothing in the build. The script creates obstacles for the player to jump over.

Note: This is a 2D project in unity version 2021.3.15f1 and I am building on a Windows machine.

The script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tree;
    public GameObject cannonbob;
    public GameObject snail;
    public int cooldown = 2500;
    public int spawnOffset = 10;
    public bool doSpawn = true; 
    
    private int cooldownIndex = 0; //How far through the cooldown it is.
    private GameObject player;
    private bool mustSpawn = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().isDead == false && player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().won == false && player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().stopSpawning == false){
            if(cooldownIndex < cooldown) {
                cooldownIndex += 1;
            } else {
                cooldownIndex = 1;
                // Note minInclusive & maxExclusive when using random range
                if(mustSpawn == true){
                    SpawnObstacle();
                    mustSpawn = false;
                } else {
                    if(Random.Range(0,2) == 1) { 
                        SpawnObstacle();
                    } else {
                        cooldownIndex = 2000;
                        mustSpawn = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    void SpawnObstacle(){
        if(doSpawn==true){
            var position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + spawnOffset, -2.13f, 0);
            int randNo = Random.Range(0,3);
            if(randNo == 0){
                Instantiate(tree, position, Quaternion.identity);
            } else if(randNo == 1){
                Instantiate(cannonbob, position, Quaternion.identity);
            } else {
                Instantiate(snail, position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also do not know if there is a way to debug in the build and I am unable to find the log file in the build.

The script is attached to an empty game object in the scene.

[image: Image of GameObject]

Upon building, there is also a warning:

> Unable to find player assembly: C:\...\UnityProdjects\TomatoGuy\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)

This is fixed by going into project settings and unticking "Enable burst compilation"

I've uploaded [a video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEogd.jpg) to Imgur that showcases the problem more completely. Essentially it's just a screen recording of the Editor correctly running the above script, creating obstacles for the player to get over, and a recording of me building and running the project and the script not running at all.

I have restarted the editor and it still persists.

Comment: do not use `cooldownIndex` int based ... make this a `float` and rather use `Time.deltaTime` accordingly .. currently your cooldown is completely dependent on the frame-rate which might be way higher in the editor than in a build ... if you assume a normal 60 frames per second than a cooldown of 2500 frames takes around 41 seconds ... your video didn't wait that long ...

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH @derHugo!! I changed it accordingly and it works. Sorry I didn't reply for a while but I appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by using `Time.deltaTime`. Thanks to @derHugo for the help!